# Transform tabular data from wide to long format using python or C#

Tags: python, csv, transformation

I have csv file like following,

| respondant_id | 10410 | 10411 | 10412 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | P12 | P13 | P14 |
| Y | P18 | P19 | P147 |

I want this to be transformed like following, using python or C#

| respondant_id | internal_location | ccp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 10410 | P12 |
| X | 10411 | P13 |
| X | 10412 | P14 |
| Y | 10410 | P18 |
| Y | 10411 | P19 |
| Y | 10412 | P147 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` feature of `pandas` to achieve this transformation. If `df` is the pandas DataFrame containing your data then the transformation is

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['respondant_id'], value_vars=['10410', '10411', '10412'], var_name='internal_location', value_name='ccp')
```